# I want to short the URL using rewrite rules using .htaccess. how can i do that?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to short the URL `http://app.test/pages/product-detail.php?men-new-watches` to `http://app.test/product/detail/men-new-watches` OR `http://app.test/product/men-new-watches` using `.htaccess`. How can I do that?

I Have Written this but it not works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ product-detail.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the obvious answer to your question is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?product/men-new-watches$ /pages/product-detail.php?men-new-watches [END]
```

If you want the argument to be dynamic, however, then probably that is the variant you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?product/([\w-]+)$ /pages/product-detail.php?$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).